# Django dynamic modelform

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to add a django modelform that allows to add job offers with dynamic skills fields, that appear on button clicks, so the user decides what are the skills attached to each offer and save all of that as one instance in the database.
I've searched on how to do that with no luck so far..

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem ? E.g. what is your current database structure, maybe an example of your model\form ?

Comment: hi sorry for my late answer, so i'm basecally trying to create a job posting modelform based on this model :                                                                                                                 class Recruit(models.Model):
    Description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    skills = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=200, null=True)
    check = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Description

Comment: but i dont want thefield skills to be static, i want to have some functionalities that allows the user to decides whether to add skills and what skills to add on button clicks, i hope this make sense.